# Get response from server in JWT

Tags: kotlin, jwt, android-volley, bearer-token

I have the following code, where I validate the JWT token (with volley):

```
private fun validateToken(token: String) {

        var queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val yourUrl = "https://mysite/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate"

        val parameters = JSONObject()
        try {
            parameters.put("username", "abc@test.com")
            parameters.put("password", "12345678")
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        }
        val request: JsonObjectRequest =
            object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Method.POST, yourUrl, parameters,
                Response.Listener { response -> Log.i("onResponse", response.toString()) },
                Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.e("onErrorResponse", error.toString()) }) {
                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                    val headers: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                    // Basic Authentication
                    //String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(CONSUMER_KEY_AND_SECRET.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"
                    return headers
                }




            }
        queue.add(request)
    }
```

It works for me and I get the correct response from the server (in Log.i):

```
{"code":"jwt_auth_valid_token","data":{"status":200}}
```

My question is how in my code I do to be able to save the `status: 200` in a variable so then it applies an ʻif status == 200` and if it is 200 then send it to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add  `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` to build.gradle(app)
2. Create `Model.tk` with:

   ```
   data class dataServer (

       @SerializedName("code") val code : String,
       @SerializedName("data") val data : Data
   )

   data class Data (

           @SerializedName("status") val status : Int
       )
   ```

```
3. Update code:




    private fun validateToken(token: String) {
    
            var queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    
            val yourUrl = "https://myweb/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate"
    
            val parameters = JSONObject()
            try {
                parameters.put("username", "abc@test.com")
                parameters.put("password", "12345678")
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            }
            val request: JsonObjectRequest =
                object : JsonObjectRequest(
                    Method.POST, yourUrl, parameters,
                    Response.Listener {
                        response ->
                        Log.i("onResponse", response.toString())
    
    
                        val gson = Gson()
                        val dataToken   = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), dataServer::class.java)
    
                        val status = dataToken.data.status
    
             
                        println(status)
                       // use here if then
       
    
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.e("onErrorResponse", error.toString()) }) {
                    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                        val headers: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                        // Basic Authentication
                        //String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(CONSUMER_KEY_AND_SECRET.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"
                        return headers
                    }
    
    
    
    
                }
            queue.add(request)
        }
```